# JsonValueProviderFactory not binding on some machines

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

We have a simple project that uses JsonValueProviderFactory which we have working on a number of machines however it does not bind when running it on a number of other machines. This says to me that it is a machine setup issue rather than a code issue but I do not know exactly what JsonValueProviderFactory requires to work correctly. It may be something missing or maybe something is installed on these machines that it doesn't like.

Any pointers as to what I can investigate on these machines would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE:

I did as Darin Dimitrov suggested and the new project worked so I then processed to duplicate the original project (it was only small) and eventually tracked down the issue. It was simply an issue in the Web.config. It had the following  section in the config which did not work on some of the machines:

```
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="LowerCaseRule1" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="[A-Z]" ignoreCase="false" />
                <action type="Redirect" url="{ToLower:{URL}}" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
```

Comment: glad u solved your problem. but Darin at least deserves an upvote for guiding in right direction

Comment: Can you provide further info as to why this was stopping JSON binding?

Answer (score 3):

Here's something you could try which might rule out the *machine factor* and narrow down the problem. Create a new application from scratch following the [following blog post](http://haacked.com/archive/2010/04/15/sending-json-to-an-asp-net-mvc-action-method-argument.aspx) step by step. Then ensure that this application works over all machines (it should unless you did something wrong). Then if it doesn't work on some machine post your results here, define what *not works mean* and we might be able to help.

If this works, then the problem is with your application. Unfortunately as you haven't told much about it that's all I can think of currently.